# Which of the combinations of "yelling," "screaming," and "shouting" sounds more natural to your ear?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Which of the combinations in the sentence below sounds more natural to your ear?

I felt disrespected so I just completely lost my cool and started yelling and screaming. (1)

- yelling and shouting. (2)
- screaming and yelling. (3)
- screaming and shouting. (4)
- shouting and yelling. (5)
- shouting and screaming. (6)

Answer (score 0):

The options with both **yelling** and **shouting** should be excluded, because the meanings of the two words are too close.
That leaves the options that included **screaming**; that is more intense than **yelling** or **shouting**, so it should come second, to avoid anticlimax.

That leaves 1 and 6. They are very close, but 6 sounds more natural to me.